# matplotlib plot set x_ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, linegraph

How would I set the x_axis labels at the indices 1,2,3....n  to be something different.

```
lam_beta = [(lam1,beta1),(lam1,beta2),(lam1,beta3),....(lam_n,beta_n)]
chunks = [chunk1,chunk2,...chunk_n]
ht_values_per_chunk = {chunk1:[val1,val2,...],chunk2:[val1,val2,val3,.....]...}
color='rgbycmk'
     j=0
     for chunk in chunks:
        plt.plot([hr_values_per_chunk[chunk][i] for i,item in enumerate(lam_beta)],[i for i,item in enumerate(lam_beta)],color=j%len(color))
        j+=1

     plt.set_xticks([i for i,item in enumerate(lam_beta)])
     plt.set_xticklabels([item for item in lam_beta],rotation='vertical')
     plt.show()
```

Error:

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'set_xticks'

Here I am unable to set the values of the lambda_beta tuple to be the values of each of the ticks on the x-axis as it say plt has no such method. How would I be able to achieve this for plt? I used xticks because this is how I had done it while generating a histogram in matplotlib. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 33):

[set_xticks](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks) and [set_xticklabels](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels) are axes methods, not functions in the `plt` module namespace. This is the meaning of the error message, `'module' object has no attribute 'set_xticks'`.

Moreover,

```
[i for i,item in enumerate(lam_beta)]
```

can be simplified to

```
range(len(lam_beta))
```

and

```
[item for item in lam_beta]
```

can be simplified to

```
lam_beta
```

A convenient way to get your hands on the `axes` is to call 
[plt.subplots](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots):

So:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
...
ax.set_xticks(range(len(lam_beta)))
ax.set_xticklabels(lam_beta, rotation='vertical')
```

`ax` is an `Axes` object. Calling `Axes` methods is the object-oriented approach to using matplotlib.

---

Alternatively, you could use the Matlab-style `pylab` interface by calling [`plt.xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html). If we define

```
loc = range(len(lam_beta))
labels = lam_beta
```

then

```
plt.xticks(loc, labels, rotation='vertical')
```

is equivalent to

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xticks(loc)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation='vertical')
```

`plt.xticks` sets the tick locations and labels to the current axes.

---

The list comprehension

```
[hr_values_per_chunk[chunk][i] for i,item in enumerate(lam_beta)]
```

could be simplified to

```
hr_values_per_chunk[chunk][:len(lam_beta)]
```

And you could eschew setting the `color` parameter for each call to `ax.plot` by using [ax.set_color_cycle](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_color_cycle):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
lam_beta = [(lam1,beta1),(lam1,beta2),(lam1,beta3),....(lam_n,beta_n)]
chunks = [chunk1,chunk2,...chunk_n]
ht_values_per_chunk = {chunk1:[val1,val2,...],chunk2:[val1,val2,val3,.....]...}
color='rgbycmk'
ax.set_color_cycle(colors)

for chunk in chunks:
    vals = hr_values_per_chunk[chunk][:len(lam_beta)]
    ax.plot(vals, range(len(lam_beta)))

ax.set_xticks(range(len(lam_beta)))
ax.set_xticklabels(lam_beta, rotation='vertical')
plt.show()
```